# Unable to make after_create to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a ticket booking app for my sample project using Ruby on Rails 4.1. Three are three models - Events, Tickets and Bookings. Events have many tickets and bookings. Tickets have many bookings and they belong to events. Bookings belongs to events and tickets.

Here's the ticket model:

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  has_many :bookings
  belongs_to :user

  validates :ticket_name, :terms_conditions, presence: true
  validates_date :booking_start_date, on: :create, on_or_after: :today
  validates_date :booking_end_date, after: :booking_start_date
  validates :ticket_price, presence: true, numericality: true
  validates :ticket_quantity, :minimum_quantity, :maximum_quantity, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true }

  before_create :check_start_date
  before_update :check_start_date


    def check_start_date
        if (self.booking_start_date >= DateTime.now) && (self.booking_end_date != DateTime.now)
            self.status = 'Open'
        else
            self.status = 'Closed'
        end
    end

    def maximum_tickets_allowed
        (1..maximum_quantity.to_i).to_a
    end
end
```

The bookings model:

```
    class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base

      belongs_to :event
      belongs_to :ticket
      has_many :charges

      validates :buyer_name, presence: true
      validates :order_quantity, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true }
      validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: /\A[^@\s]+@([^@.\s]+\.)+[^@.\s]+\z/ }

      def total_amount
        ticket.ticket_price.to_i * order_quantity.to_i
      end

      def check_ticket_count
        count = ticket.ticket_quantity.to_i - order_quantity.to_i
        ticket.update_attribute(:ticket_quantity, count)
      end
    end

The bookings controller:

class BookingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:index, :destroy]

  def index
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    #@bookings = @event.bookings.all
    @bookings = @event.bookings.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
  end

  def new
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @ticket = @event.tickets.find(params[:ticket_id])
    @booking = Booking.new
  end

  def create
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @ticket = @event.tickets.find(params[:ticket_id])
    @booking = @event.bookings.create(booking_params)
    @booking.ticket = @ticket

    Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]
    #token = params[:stripeToken]
    @amount = @booking.total_amount

    begin
      customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
        :email => @booking.email,
        :card  => params[:stripeToken]
        )

      charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
        :customer    => customer.id,
        :amount => @amount,
        :currency => "usd",
        #:card => token
        )
      flash[:notice] = "Thanks for the order"
    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
      flash[:danger] = e.message
    end  
    if @booking.save
        BookingMailer.booking_confirmation_user(@booking).deliver
        flash[:notice] = "You've successfully booked the tickets!"
        redirect_to [@event, @booking]
    else
        render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @booking = @event.bookings.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @booking = @event.bookings.find(params[:id])
    @booking.destroy
    redirect_to event_bookings_path
  end

  private
  def booking_params
    params.require(:booking).permit(:buyer_name, :email, :mobile, :address, :order_quantity, :ticket_id)
  end
end
```

The check_ticket_count method in Booking.rb works fine as long as I don't an add after_create :check_ticket_count method. The moment I add that after_create method, the app throws the "undefined method `ticket_quantity' for nil:NilClass" error. How to get past this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should first associate ticket with booking, and only then create booking.

```
@booking = @event.bookings.new(booking_params)
@booking.ticket = @ticket
@booking.save
```

Hopefully you will ask questions with less code next time.

Comment: Do you mean to say I should replace bookings.create with bookings.new?

Comment: At least you should try.

Comment: Normally nobody helps with that questions ;)